# Why does Django ORM not find related object in post_delete signal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-signals

When I delete a PumpLog I delete the related Invoice via on_delete = models.CASCADE. Invoices have a post_delete signal that queries on that relationship (see the line with `#ERROR`).

So it goes: user deletes PumpLog -> which triggers delete Invoice -> which triggers Invoice post_delete signal

models.py

```
class PumpLog(BasicModelFields):
    gallons = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    pump_log = models.ForeignKey('PumpLog', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

def post_invoice_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.pump_log #ERROR
    # or
    print(instance.pump_log_id) #displays the correct id. But the below query fails.
    PumpLog.objects.filter(index = instance.pump_log_id) #ERROR
```

The error:

```
records.models.PumpLog.DoesNotExist: PumpLog matching query does not exist.
```

I understand to some degree that the PumpLog could be deleted [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#post-delete):

> Note that the object will no longer be in the database, so be very
> careful what you do with this instance.

Technically this warning refers to the Invoice in this case NOT the PumpLog. Plus in PGAdmin I can query the database directly and see the PumpLog and Invoice are still there.

So why is the ORM having trouble finding the PumpLog?

Is the PumpLog artificially removed from the scope of the ORM even though it hasn't been removed from the database yet? Or am I not understanding this correctly?

EDIT:

```
class BasicModelFields(models.Model):
    modified = models.DateTimeField('Last Updated', auto_now=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created', auto_now_add=True, blank=True)  
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name='%(class)s_created_by_user', verbose_name = 'Created By', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name='%(class)s_modified_by_user', verbose_name = 'Modified By', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    auto_complete_look_up_field = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_column='AutoCompleteLookUpField', blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    header_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    history = AuditlogHistoryField(editable=False) #maybe add to BasicModelFields


    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the sequence of events here is something like this:

- `PumpLog` object gets deleted from the Database.
- `Invoice` object gets deleted from the Database.
- In `post_invoice_delete`, you have access to the Invoice instance. However, there is no way to access the PumpLog instance/database record, as it could only have been accessed inside a PumpLog post_delete hook receiver.

So, when you try to access `instance.pump_log`, you get a DoesNotExist exception because, simply, the PumpLog object does not exist in the database, or anywhere, anymore.
I believe that the line just returns None rather than raising a DoesNotExist exception.

```py
    PumpLog.objects.filter(index = instance.pump_log_id)
```

It should only raise an exception if you use `get()` in place of `filter()`.

As to why you can still access `instance.pump_log__id`, I believe that it's simply because the ID of the pump_log is accessible by the `Invoice` instance itself as a result of the `ForeignKey` column that probably exists in the database and, thus, translating into an attribute on the object itself, making it unnecessary for the ORM to access the database. Only when you do something that needs to read the `PumpLog` object from the data do you get the error.

If you indeed do need access to the `PumpLog` instance, perhaps you should do what you need to do in a `post_log_post_delete` receiver, which should be able to access the Invoice instance since that would probably still exist.

Comment: Great thanks Dakshraj. I think I will do that. But I'm wondering - you say "you get a DoesNotExist exception because, simply, the PumpLog object does not exist in the database". But I check the database afterwards and it's still actually there.

Comment: Apologies for my un-tested answer. Attempting to replicate your code on my system, it works exactly as you expect it to. The only change being to replace `index` with `id` in the line `PumpLog.objects.filter(index = instance.pump_log_id)`.
You might need to provide some insight into what `BasicModelFields` is. Is it a custom class that might be affecting the deletion behavior of the PumpLog object?

Comment: Thanks for trying to replicate. I added BasicModelFields to the end of the question after 'Edit:'.

Comment: Hi Liam. Apologies, I am unable to narrow down why you are facing the issue. But one thing that I can confirm to you is that if the post_delete receiver `post_invoice_delete` raises an exception and doesn't succeed, both the PumpLog and the Invoice instance do indeed remain in the database (that is, they don't get deleted). This is perhaps due to the transactional behavior of Django, where Database queries are not made until a complete request succeeds.

Comment: Ok thanks for the follow-up. That makes me wonder if it be being rolled-back? Perhaps it does actually delete it and then hits the error and then rolls the whole transaction back. Either way thanks.